# make a Carbon Server WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i'm microservice developer in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator and for the create orchestration flows i use Integration Studio 8.0 IDE, well, i maked an API with a class mediator for execute a JAVA class [following this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw5TaSy4k_c&t=1212s).
i maked all steps to the letter exactly how to indicates the person in the video.

In the video tutorial in 19:55 minute he use WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.9.0 and i have WSO2 Enterprise Service, then for execute the WSO Enterprise in my case i use the 3 next comands:

```
    •   Start Micro Integrator as a service    $ sudo wso2mi-service start 
    •   Start Micro Integrator Dashboard as a service    $ sudo wso2mi-dashboard-service start 
    •   Start Streaming Integrator as a service    $ sudo wso2si-service start
```

with this i run my WSO2 services to run and deploys APIs but the problema is when i going add a Remote Carbon Server i get the nexts errors:

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qILhL.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kaHp.png)

i can't established a conection for https://localhost:9443/ like at the 20:34 minute in the video tutorial.

additional to this i cant enter to https://localhost:9443/carbon trought my web browser, i only can access to Micro Integrator Dashboard trought https://localhost:9743/dashboard. what i should to make a correctly conection from my Remote Carbon Server IDE manager to my WSO2 htpps://localhost:9443/ server?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `https://localhost:9443/` was used by WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0 and previous versions as the management console. But from WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.0.0(Micro Integrator 1.0.0) onwards we have removed the management console and you can use the Micro Integrator Dashboard for monitoring purposes.

We have recently added the support to add a MI server as a remote server in the **Integration studio 8.2.0**. You may need to update the studio to the latest version to use this feature.

With this improvement, the Add New Server dialog will look as follows, where you need to use `https://localhost:9164/management` as the server URL to connect to the remote Micro Integrator.

[image]

Comment: what are the default credentials acces? i put ADMIN/ADMIN and i get an error message :(

Comment: @ArmandoRojasValdez, the default credentials are admin/admin (lowercase). Do you see any errors in remote MI server?